# Data Entities Connection String Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception, connection-string

I must have changed something somewhere, but damned if I can figure out what it is.

I have a DAL that handles all my data access (as is a DAL's wont) to my SQL Server DB.  This includes the Entity Model, the repository classes and the connection string in the App.Config file.

Somewhere along the piece, I must have changed something and am now getting the following exception every time I try to view a page on my MVC application:

> The specified named connection is
>   either not found in the configuration,
>   not intended to be used with the
>   EntityClient provider, or not valid.

This is any page that inherits `<IEnumerable<DataAccess.Layer.Class>>`.  What am I missing?

*Connection String:*

```
<add name="JobTrackEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/JobTrackDataModel.csdl|res://*/JobTrackDataModel.ssdl|res://*/JobTrackDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Users\Phil\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\JobTrack\trunk\JobTrack\App_Data\JobTrack.MDF&quot;;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

*Designer.cs snippet:*

```
public JobTrackEntities() : 
        base("name=JobTrackEntities", "JobTrackEntities")
{
    this.OnContextCreated();
}
/// <summary>
/// Initialize a new JobTrackEntities object.
/// </summary>
public JobTrackEntities(string connectionString) : 
        base(connectionString, "JobTrackEntities")
{
    this.OnContextCreated();
}
/// <summary>
/// Initialize a new JobTrackEntities object.
/// </summary>
public JobTrackEntities(global::System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection) : 
        base(connection, "JobTrackEntities")
{
    this.OnContextCreated();
}
```

Comment: Are you using a Linq2SQL dbml class?

Comment: No, I'm using the ADO.Net Entity Data Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring your **ADO.NET entity project** in **another project** then take a look at

http://blogs.msdn.com/bindeshv/archive/2009/09/04/referring-ado-net-entity-project-in-a-different-project.aspx

Comment: That's automatically inserted by the ORM designer in Visual Studio.  My understanding is that it will convert those HTML codes to their string equivalents when the App.Config file's XML is parsed.  However, if anyone else can confirm that this could be an issue, I'd like to know.

Comment: If you are referring your ADO.NET entity project in another project then take a look at 


http://blogs.msdn.com/bindeshv/archive/2009/09/04/referring-ado-net-entity-project-in-a-different-project.aspx

Comment: @Rasik.  Well done, that man! I knew it would be something simple.  You should enter this as the actual answer so I can accept it as the solution and upvote it.

Comment: Phil, As per your comment, I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever i use a S2L dbml class I run into the same problem when i make a change to the dbml file via the interface and not in code.

it resets my connection string and i need to change it back to read from web.config.

don't know if this is your issue @Phil.

if not, could you provide more information?

Comment: Well, I looked at that and the designer.cs file still references the correct connection string and doesn't seem to have any other connection details cached anywhere.  I'll add the source in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

The **only** other thing I can see that **may** cause a problem is the use of the hard coded path.  Have you tried inserting a \?

```
C:\\Users\\Phil\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\JobTrack\\trunk\\JobTrack\\App_Data\\JobTrack.MDF
```

> > Also I trust you've checked and double checked the path is correct? :)
> >
> > Have you tried getting the server path and then adding app_data\jobtrack.mdf to it?
> >
> > Have you tried getting rid of the path entirley?  I ask because, and I forget under what circumstances this is correct, .Net will infer the path and app_data folder when attaching to a database.  again, you need to research this.
> >
> > Also sometimes running the ASP.NET Configuration utility can fix the project, break the project or identify where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after attempting to fix it many differant ways I had the idea that VS was bugging out so I simplified the solution with new projects (entity framework and a test project), copied the config file from the dll into the test project and I recieved the same error. I then deleted the config file from the test project, added a new config file, copied the connection string content to the config file and it worked.